# If we were to discover an alien ecosystem that has a D-configuration of proteins, how would it react to our L-sided biology?

Tags: virology, protein-structure, amino-acids, environment

I'm concepting a hard-sci-fi story where a scientist discovers microorganisms in our solar system with disastrous results. I was thinking about how any cross-contamination with an alien ecosystem would cause the organism to self-destruct like matter, anit-matter. I'm more inspired by science fiction works like War of the Worlds, The Andromeda Strain, Annihilation, etc., but I'm also interested in explaining how alien life could have evolved with novel-yet-similar mechanisms than life on earth.

Leading me to the whole L-sided vs D-sided amino acids and protein synthesis. So how would the organisms interact with each other? I was thinking all the cells would self-destruct leaving behind traces of organic material and a myriad of novel viruses. Any material, references, or input is always appreciated. Thanks

Comment: L- and D- are not matter and anti-matter. Racemic mixtures of enantiomers are common in chemistry here on earth, you don't need to imagine some fictional world. You could consider some particular cases of "wrong-handed" molecules, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-Glucose You could also consider that in a fictional story you can do whatever you want, that's why it's fiction, and consider that the interesting parts of science fiction are typically the statements and reflection on the condition of humankind. The rest just helps drive the plot.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange. I think your question might be more suitable for the [Worldbuilding StackExchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) where you can find plenty of similar "hypothetical" questions.

Comment: I think it's important for creative writing to be grounded. Not just in realism, but (since poetry is my passion) also with form. This is also my own opinion about the Fermi Paradox, where life in the universe has no interest in looking for new life because of incompatibility with each other. L- and D- are concepts I'd heard about, so I was curious how a D- evolved ecosystem might interact with our L- evolved ecosystem hypothetically.

Comment: One of the reasons I **love** Isaac Asimov's science fiction is the science is accurate, which made the stories more relatable to me (a science-field major), so kudos for your aim. I can't answer your question as it is, because I don't know what kind of interactions you expect might be disastrous. I don't think they would survive on earth because most of our food sources are made with L-matter, just as we could not survive on theirs. But here's an article that might help you: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/space/must-all-molecules-life-be-left-handed-or-right-handed-180959956/

Comment: On the other hand, Ray Bradbury didn't let science hold him back from writing incredible, beautiful, dreamy, nightmarish, metaphorical (you pick, he wrote them all) sci-fi. It's not about the science, it's about the story.